# Non-ASCII characters handled incorrectly on command line

Tags: bash, terminal, osx, locale, unicode

I have a problem with non-ASCII characters in the Terminal on Mac. If I write:

```
echo ÆØÅ
```

Then press Enter, Arrow Up, Arrow Left, so the cursor is between the Ø and the Å, then write X, then the Å is converted to ?, and if I press Enter, the following is echoed:

```
ÆØ?X?
```

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> with non-ASCII characters entered also causes a mess.

My settings are as follows:

```
~/.profile:
export LC_ALL="nb_NO.UTF-8"

~/.inputrc:
set input-meta on
set output-meta on
set convert-meta off

Terminal > Settings > Advanced > Declare terminal as: xterm
```

Unsetting `LC_ALL` has no effect. Changing the `.inputrc` settings just seems to make things worse.

I really hope someone has the answer to this.

Comment: What version of `bash`? Older versions of `bash` didn't support editing UTF8 text very well

Comment: Are you sure `nb_NO.UTF-8` is a valid locale name on your system? Does it show up in the output of `locale -a`? What does `locale charmap` tell you?

Comment: Could you post that as an answer so the question can be marked as answered please?

Answer (score 2):

nb_NO.UTF-8 did indeed not exist. Changing to no_NO.UTF-8 solved the problem. Actually, the problem was introduced by LANG=C which was set for some other reason. Removing this makes OS X set LC_CTYPE=UTF-8 by default, which works out of the box.